# Ruby 2.6.5 with jemalloc

Tags: ruby, jemalloc

I've built and installed rub 2.6.5 from source with jemalloc. However when I check to see if its there I'm not seeing an entry.  Is there something else I should have been doing?

```
ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ip-10-0-3-198 4.15.0-1032-aws #34-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 17 15:18:09 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ubuntu:~$ ./configure --enable-shared --with-jemalloc
ubuntu:~$ make
ubuntu:~$ make install
```

Which results in:

```
ubuntu:~$ ruby -r rbconfig -e "puts RbConfig::CONFIG['LIBS']"
-lm
```

Tracking memory usage once deployed I'm also not seeing a drop compared to similarly configured servers without jemalloc in place.

I'm not sure what I need to be doing in order to get jemalloc working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
puts RbConfig::CONFIG['MAINLIBS']
```

And check for `-ljemalloc` in the output.

This behavior has changed recently (in 2.6.x, to be precise).

Comment: Thanks! I do indeed see `jemalloc` in the list: "$ ruby -r rbconfig -e "puts RbConfig::CONFIG['MAINLIBS']"
-lz -lpthread -lrt -lrt -ljemalloc -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm"

Comment: Thanks. Sadly not really seeing an improvement in memory usage though. Back to the investigation.

Answer (score 8):

For some reason, the accepted answer does not work for me (Heroku), but this:

`MALLOC_CONF=stats_print:true ruby -e "exit"`

has done the trick.

If you have some stats ouput, means it's working.

source: https://github.com/gaffneyc/heroku-buildpack-jemalloc/issues/5#issuecomment-499932026

Answer (score 0):

For ones using `LD_PRELOAD` and not building ruby directly, a more complete answer would be:

```rb
RbConfig::CONFIG['MAINLIBS'].include?("jemalloc") || ENV['LD_PRELOAD'].include?("jemalloc")
```

Of course this is not enough to tell if jemalloc really is working, as for the accepted answer!