# Do I need to build Ruby with jemalloc and use the gem if I'm using a Heroku buildpack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems, jemalloc

Sample a **Ruby (2.4.1)** on **Rails (4.2.8)** app, configured with Puma and deployed on **Heroku (cedar-16)**. Currently developing on a **Mojave 10.14.5** MBP. I'm on a mission to cut down memory usage and recently discovered jemalloc [via this post](https://medium.com/rubyinside/how-we-halved-our-memory-consumption-in-rails-with-jemalloc-86afa4e54aa3). I reinstalled Ruby (using RVM) with jemalloc enabled as proved by the following output - `-lpthread -ljemalloc -lgmp -ldl -lobjc`. I proceeded to add the [jemalloc gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/jemalloc/versions/1.0.1) and bundle installed without a problem. I've also set up the [Heroku buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/gaffneyc/heroku-buildpack-jemalloc) and configured necessary environment variables.

However, with the gem in my Gemfile, I'm unable to run any rake/rails commands - `rails c` returns the following error, promptly followed by my Mac's fans firing up:

`ruby(45487,0x10739c5c0) malloc: *** malloc_zone_unregister() failed for 0x7fff94a3f000`

`foreman start` gets stuck at `* Preloading application`. All issues vanish & app works fine if I remove the gem.

Since I'm not privy to how Heroku buildpacks work and how that specific one is programmed exactly, my questions are as follows:

1. With the buildpack added, do I really need the gem installed in my project?
2. With the buildpack added, do I need a Ruby version compiled using jemalloc?
3. If I do need the gem, how do I get rid of the aforementioned error?

Comment: Just started to look into this and having the same questions. Did you find any answers?

Answer (score 7):

malloc gem was last released 5 years ago and it bundles a pretty old version of jemalloc lib (v3.4 and currently we have v5.2).
All the gem does, is adding jemalloc lib to `LD_PRELOAD` (or `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` on mac os) before executing ruby binary.
It shouldn't be needed if ruby is built against jemalloc library with `--with-jemalloc` flag.

So to answer your questions:

> 1. With the buildpack added, do I really need the gem installed in my project?

No, buildpack will handle everything automatically for you while deploying to heroku.
Actually, there might be a problem with conflicting jemalloc versions if you have the gem.

> 2. With the buildpack added, do I need a Ruby version compiled using jemalloc?

For local development? Technically no. But I would advise you to use exactly the same ruby version as you use on production to avoid suprises.

> 3. If I do need the gem, how do I get rid of the aforementioned error?

You don't need the gem. You can enable jemalloc by rebuilding your ruby with `--with-jemalloc` flag (as you did).

Here's a full list of steps:

```
# install jemalloc lib locally
brew install jemalloc

# reinstall ruby (with rbenv):
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-jemalloc rbenv install 2.7.1
# or with rvm:
rvm reinstall 2.7.1 -C —with-jemalloc

# confirm ruby is using jemalloc (ruby >= 2.6)
ruby -r rbconfig -e "puts RbConfig::CONFIG['MAINLIBS']"
# or with ruby < 2.6
ruby -r rbconfig -e "puts RbConfig::CONFIG['LIBS']"
```

You might also need to rebuild gems with native extensions (though I'm not sure about this one):
See this question for how to do it: [How do I get a list of gems that are installed that have native extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165950/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-gems-that-are-installed-that-have-native-extensions)

Comment: Many thanks. I'll note that the confirmation step appears not to work for me on Heroku. Instead, I used `MALLOC_CONF=stats_print:true ruby -e "exit"` (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60883641/2752774)).